# How to read string from pointer to buffer in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, unsafe-pointers

How can I read the error string in C# from this C++ dll call?

```
//
//  PARAMETERS:
//      objptr
//          Pointer to class instance.
//
//      pBuffer
//          Pointer to buffer receiving NULL terminated error message string.   
//          If this value is zero, the function returns the required buffer size, in bytes,
//          and makes no use of the pBuffer. 
//
//      nSize
//          Size of receiving buffer.
//          If this value is zero, the function returns the required buffer size, in bytes,
//          and makes no use of the pBuffer. 
//
//  RETURN VALUES:
//      If pBuffer or nSize is zero, the function returns the required buffer size, in bytes.
//      If the function succeeds, the return value is number of bytes copied into pBuffer.
//      If function fails return value is 0.
//
extern unsafe int GetError(uint objptr, byte* pBuffer, int nSize);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
int size;
unsafe
{
  fixed ( byte* p = buffer )
  {
    size = GetError( ???, p, buffer.Length ); 
  }
}
string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString( buffer, 0, size );
```

Comment: I used GetError(???, null, 0) to get the message size in order to create the buffer and worked also perfect. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try to change byte* to StringBuilder and pass that instead and avoid the unsafe code.

Comment: @Mikael: how can I do it? The dll method expects byte*

Comment: @Dawkins: what the method really expects is a 32 bit pointer. What it points to doesn't really matter as long as it points to something that it can write to without causing a protection fault. Using a StringBuilder will work, just as Mikael says - as long as you remember to allocate sufficient memory in the StringBuilder. Since your question specifically stated a byte* and unsafe code - I just went down that road in my answer. There exists quite a few more possible solutions.

Comment: thanks danbystrom, but how should I pass the Stringbuilder? The compiler throws an exception if I just replace the byte* with it.

Comment: It should not. Not if you change the declaration and then pass it a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the data type from byte* to IntPtr this might work:

[Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi(VS.80).aspx)

Or one of the `string` constructors (one of them also includes an `Encoding` parameter):

[String Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Marshal.AllocHGlobal(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx) plus [Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(IntPtr, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/708t2k0b.aspx) perhaps?

Some code context would be nice, as I'm assuming that you're already coercing `byte*` into an `IntPtr` using p/invoke or some other trickery.

Basically, call your function to get the buffer size, allocate a buffer using `AllocHGlobal()`, call it again, read the string in, then free the buffer (using `Marshall.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr)`).  This is assuming you can use Marshall's allocator, of course.